# Jest: How to throw an error inside a unhandledRejection handler

Tags: jestjs

I have the following code:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    throw error;
});
```

But when I run jest without the `--runInBand` option this never throws, it just hangs on forever on the offending tests.

Any ideas on how to stop the process when an `unhandledRejection` is met?